# Manage API data reponse with rxjs and manage application state - Angular 10

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-services

I'm trying to understand what's the best way to store (and update) data from the api and share that data between siblings components. This is what I tried.

**Saving the observable**

```
export class MyExampleService {
   private data: Observable<any>;

   constructor(private readonly http: HttpClient) { }

   getData(): Observable<string[]> {
       //if we already got the data, just return that
       if (data) {
           return data;
       }

       //if not, get the data
       return this.http.get<string[]>('http://my-api.com/get-stuff')
           .pipe(tap((returnedData: string[]) => {
               //save the returned data so we can re-use it later without making more HTTP calls
               this.data= returnedData;
           }));
   }
}
```

But this approach doesn't really fit my needs because it doesn't use any subject and I want to tell my other components when data changes.

**Using subjects**

```
export class MyExampleService {
   private dataSbj: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(null);
   
   readonly data$ = this.dataSbj.asObservable();

   constructor(private readonly http: HttpClient) { }

   getData(): Observable<string[]> {

       if (dataSbj.getValue() === null) {
           return this.http.get<string[]>('http://my-api.com/get-stuff')
           .pipe(tap((returnedData: string[]) => {
               //save the returned data so we can re-use it later without making more HTTP calls
               this.dataSbj.next(returnedData);
           }));
       }          
   }
}
```

Then I would simply subscribe to the getData only the first time and subscribe to the data$ observable in all other components. (In this case I have one parent component and more child routes, so I would subscribe to getData() in the parent component and subscribe to the data$ in all child routes).

This last approach works but I'd rather use the same function to retrieve the same data and not by subscribing to different observables.

Is this considered a good approach or is there something better I could do instead?

Comment: store data in cookies, use authentication and authorization in you app to restrict data

Comment: this doesn't sound right. I mean you could do it, but I don't think it's the best way. I would much rather prefer in memory storing in my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `getData()` method has no parameters, you should be able to do the following by utilizing the `shareReplay()` operator. It will only call the API when the first consumers subscribes to it, and will return the last emit to any sequential calls. This also includes a way to update the data:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ExampleService {
  private updateData$ = new BehaviorSubject<void>(void 0); 

  readonly data$ = this.updateData$.pipe(
    switchMap(() => this.http.get('https://reqres.in/api/users')),
    shareReplay(1)
  );

  constructor(private readonly http: HttpClient) {}
   
  refresh(): void {
    this.updateData$.next();
  }
}
```

```
export class ExampleComponent {
  data$: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private example: ExampleService) {}

  getApi(): void {
    this.data$ = this.example.data$;
  }

  refresh(): void {
    this.example.refresh();
  }
}
```

[working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-httpclient-samples-ukwwwq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fexample.service.ts) Check the console log

Comment: How would I force to update the data in case of an update/mutation query to the API?

Comment: Thanks for the update. One more thing. If data gets updated and I want to share this new data with a component without having to refresh the page or with a new subscription to getData() how would I do it? (I think i would need a subject as I described in the second approach)

Comment: @MarcoRipamonti in that case, you should not use a function. I'll show you

Comment: I'll gladly wait for your response. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[NGRX store](https://ngrx.io/guide/store) state management is the approach to read from store if data is available instead of making unnecessary network call.

It takes care of create, update and delete records from store by dispatching relevant action.

Here is the complete source code [DEMO](https://github.com/kamrankhatti/tz-demo/tree/master/src/app/store) on github of how ngrx store is being used.

I would strongly recommend to use ngrx store it has some cool features to avoid unnecessary network calls which caused the speed up of your app.

Comment: I read this is the best approach when the application gets bigger, which is not really my case. Should I still consider this option?

Comment: 1) In future your application could also gets bigger, from start if you follow best approaches your app wont get mess when it gets bigger. 2) I dont believe its best for bigger app this is best approach to manage data and we should consider at the begging of app

Comment: @KamranKhatti for simple applications, using your own simple `BehaviorSubject` data store makes way more sense than over-complicating with a state management system, but this is obviously opinion based.

Comment: @PoulKruijt I agree but my point is today your application is simple and small tomorrow it could be evolve and be bigger in that case you dont need to refactor these types of code implementations.

Comment: @KamranKhatti but if you are sure it's not going to get bigger, you are stuck with bloatware :) especially ngrx which is extremely verbose and requires a lot of boilerplate